# Meaning of "ag"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I came across this word in a lyric (the song is *Piss Up a Rope*
by Ween):

> And you can put on your shoes, hit the road get truckin'
>   Pack your bag, I don't need the ag

What is the meaning of ag here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's "lyrics interpretation" (***ag*** has no currency as an abbreviation for ***aggravation;*** it's only used here for the sake of rhyme/scansion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At https://genius.com/14590982, a site with user-submitted song lyrics and annotations with additional explanations (again, submitted by random people like you and me, but sometimes the very authors of the lyrics), you can find the following comment addressing that specific word:

> The word “ag” is short for aggravation.

Some users have expressed doubts about the accuracy of **the rest** of the commentary linked above, so I implore you to exercise caution while navigating the link.

---

There's another source I have found that corroborates the meaning above: [OnlineSlangDictionary.com, definition of *ag*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/ag):

> also a diminutive form of *aggro*.

with *aggro* being defined [as follows](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/aggro):

> aggravation. Also abbreviated **ag**, but pronounced in its full form in south-east England and other areas. To "look for aggro" is to look for a fight.
>
> > He's been getting a bit of aggro from his boss.

Note that both of these definitions were submitted in 1997 and 1998, which is around the same time the song quoted in the question came out ([1996 according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piss_Up_a_Rope)).

---

There's also *ag*, an interjection, recorded by multiple dictionaries, and it signifies something similar, but is etymologically, or so it seems, divorced from the diminutive described above.

[Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ag) says:

> #### ag
>
> Pronunciation /æx/, /əx/
>
> *South African*
>   Used to express a range of emotions from irritation or grief to pleasure.
>
> > ‘ag man, there's nothing anyone can do’
>
> ---
>
> **Origin**
>   Afrikaans, from Dutch *ach*.

Take a look at the pronunciation and you'll notice it's actually not pronounced with a "hard g" (i.e. /ɡ/), but rather with a KH sound denoted /x/, which sounds like the harsh H sound in *Bach*.

We can therefore exclude this as our candidate because otherwise the rhyme wouldn't be preserved. (If you listen to the (wonderful, if I may add) song you'll hear it's pronounced with a "hard g".)

---

To conclude, it seems this slang term isn't really something English-speaking people recognize today (at least judging by the comments), so I wouldn't use it, except perhaps if I wanted to deliberately imitate that sort of style / slang.

Comment: That link is hopelessly misleading. It's true that *in this specific context*, "ag" is a (non-standard, "one-off") abbreviation for "aggravation", but the "contributor" who points that out goes on to claim that ***to nag*** (to scold, complain) derives from the same "original". Which is complete poppycock.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I only quoted the relevant part, which I think is correct. The link is there so that the source doesn't go uncredited.

Comment: You don’t limit the link, you link to the complete thing so it is very misleading and incorrect.

Comment: @SolarMike The rest of the comment on that website is only tangentially pertinent to the matter anyway. I never claimed that everything on that Web page is accurate.

Comment: You did not limit it either, and as the other comment says it is “poppycock”.

Comment: I haven't downvoted this answer, because it's perfectly true that *in the specified context*, "ag" means "aggravation". But this shouldn't be taken as implying that you can use the abbreviation in other contexts and expect it to be understood. It's effectively a one-off coinage for the sake of the context (which context allows us to easily figure out the intended meaning even though we've probably never heard it before). But it's just not what I see as a useful question encapsulating information that would be of more general use to ***learners***.

Comment: I agree the question doesn't really belong here, which is why I answered it as CW. I don't know how much of a nonce usage *ag* is, however.

Comment: I downvoted, because by not elaborating, the answer implies "ag" is a standard, common and/or accepted abbreviation for "aggression." It is not.

Comment: @TypeIA The question is a little more precise, and the answer was written accordingly. The term means "aggravation" there, it seems.

Comment: I'm not sure all readers will make that distinction. A simple edit to make the point clear would save this answer and reverse my vote.